# Asyc function for more than one user Node.js

Tags: node.js, concurrency

Because i is global variable being reached by more than one user, would user2 be started afer user1 executes all the code? How to work Node.js single thread?

Output:

6
a
Promise { undefined }
7
7
er

```
var i=5;

async function a(){
  i++;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(i);

  })

  console.log(i);

   setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(i);

  })
  i++;

}

async function b(){

  console.log('a');

  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("er");

  })
}


a();
b();
```

Answer (score 0):

When we call a(). the function a() is added to the stack. Inside a() there is setTimeout which should be handled by web API and web API looks after it. then it sees console.log(i) in the stack it prints the console.log. Next, There is another setTimeout which is also handled to web API. Later function b() is pushed to the stack there it finds console.log("a") and it logs, then it finds setTimeout and it is pushed to web API. After the stack is empty it returns undefined normally but here the function is asynchronous so it returns a promise of undefined. Later when the event queue sees stack is empty it allocates code inside setTimeout to load into the stack and it executes and after execution, it pops out.

Comment: During this process, if another one executes the same code? For example after the first  setTimeOut, Can Node.js be switched to another user call?

Comment: No. It follows the order of the function call. And there is libuv in node js which is a thread pool. When an asynchronous work comes node handles it to the thread pool to handle that work. libuv is not present in chrome's v8 engine, it  is only there in node.